# A way to merge multiple queues

Tags: mysql, mariadb, select, queue

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `multiqueue` (
    `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `CustomerID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `Volume` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Content` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `PublishedTS` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

This table serves as a multi-queue, meaning that it aggregates the queues of requests coming from multiple customers (denoted by `CustomerID`), each request having a certain `Volume` of work.

How to write a query that will select top `N` rows from the table, interleaving the rows from different customers?

If customer 1 sends 100 requests, each of volume 1000, then customer 2 sends 20 requests, each of volume 300, I would like that the query doesn't force any of the customers to starve on responses while my program is busy handling the requests of another customer. It should take 1 request of customer 1 and 3-4 requests of customer 2 in the first fetch, process them, then take 1 more request of customer 1 and 3-4 requests of customer 2, and so on.

What I have tried so far:

```
SET @runtot := 0;
SELECT q1.id1, q1.customerId1, q1.volume1, q1.content1, (@runtot := @runtot + q1.volume1) AS rt
FROM (
  SELECT ID AS id1, CustomerID AS customerId1, Content AS content1
  FROM multiqueue
  ORDER BY id1
) AS q1
WHERE @runtot < 2000
```

As [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109887/1915854), the code above limits the number of items selected with a running total of some field in the rows selected. In the scenario above, customer 2 would starve when the above query is in use.

The database in use is MariaDB (version 10.4.13, but I can upgrade to the latest if needed), though a solution for MySQL should also work.

Comment: maradb looses the order of the subquery, so you need to add a limit:  further, to satisfy all customers, you must have a loop,, that runs toll all request are done, and a knowledge of all fulfilled requests already.

Comment: What version of mysql, MariaDB?

Comment: @Lennart, I've edited the question to specify the version. Basically you can assume the latest version.

Comment: Ok, then you can have a look at my answer. MariaDB 10,MYSQL 8 should be ok with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For recent versions, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT ID, CustomerID, Volume, Content, runtot
FROM ( 
    SELECT ID
         , CustomerID
         , Content
         , sum(Volume) over (
                partition by CustomerID 
                order by ID
           ) as runtot
    FROM multiqueue
) AS q1 
WHERE runtot < 2000;
```

EDIT:

If you want at least 1 row for each customer, you can add another window function `ROW_NUMBER()` that enumerates the result, and use that in your select:

```
SELECT ID, CustomerID, Volume, Content, runtot
FROM ( 
    SELECT ID
         , CustomerID
         , Content
         , sum(Volume) over (
                partition by CustomerID 
                order by ID
           ) as runtot
         , row_number() over (
                partition by CustomerID 
                order by ID
           ) as rn

    FROM multiqueue
) AS q1 
WHERE runtot < 2000
   OR rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It mostly works, but I've read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/ and I still don't understand how it works. Could you elaborate? Also, when all the requests have a `Volume` of 2000 or greater, the query produces no results. How to change the query so that it produces at least one row for each customer even if that row's `Volume` exceeds 2000?

Comment: Also, if the query has a filter condition like `WHERE PublishedTS IS NULL`, do I need to add an index like `(PublishedTS, CustomerID, ID)`? Or in general, what indexes does such query need? It takes several seconds on a table having ~2K records for me without additional indexes.

Comment: Regarding window functions, have you had a look at the more elaborative examples at MariaDB like: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/introduction-to-window-functions-in-mariadb-server-10-2/

Comment: Is PublishedTS an attribute that you excluded from your table? The index you mention probably helps. A filtered index would probably be the best choise, but AFAIK MySQL, MariaDB does not support them.

Comment: Yes, I excluded the majority of fields with `PublishedTS` among them. I've edited the question to add it back.

Answer (score 0):

"Don't queue it, just do it."  That is, don't bother to put the request(s) in a queue(s), spin off a process to work through the task(s).  That leaves it up to the OS to share resources.  And avoids several nasties that *may* happen when you try to use MySQL as a Queue.

Comment: Some problems with this approach:
1) Durability: If the process terminates, the task is lost.
2) Multi-processing: actually we use the DB to distribute the tasks from multiple producers to multiple consumers.
3) Result storage: the DB is backup storage of the task results in case inter-process communication is not immediately available.